# Android Studio, show full WebView in new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I am really new at android and I am trying to make a simple app, where a view shows a webview in full size.
I have started a new project with a navigation drawer and added four menus that only shows a textfield. One of the menu tabs is called ECG. When I go to the menu and click this I want the view of this tab to show a webview in full screen - not in a browser.
I have created a webview in the xml file, but I cant figure out how to render a website in that view.

I hope you guys can help me out! Thanks in advance!

**My MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.nybroe.blivredder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
private CharSequence mTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment objFragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            objFragment = new FrontPage();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new ECG();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new Electrodes();
            break;
        case 3:
            objFragment = new Arrhythmia();
            break;

    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 0:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section0);
            break;
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

}
```

**My ECG.java**

```
package com.nybroe.blivredder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class ECG extends Fragment{
WebView web_view;
View rootview;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ecg_main, container, false);
    return rootview;
}


}
```

**My ecg_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView1">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hey man, I am benefited from your questions. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class ECG extends Fragment{
    WebView web_view;
    View rootview;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ecg_main, container, false);
        web_view = (WebView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

and in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView1">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you Juan but where do I define the loadURL method? Just under the web_view?

Comment: Yes:
web_view.loadUrl(url);

and don't forget to add this permission in manifest:
<uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.INTERNET” />